# Rails rendering ul li list with will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I'm using will_paginate in my rails application, it's working fine but I would like to use ul li list for my webdesigner layout. Actually with my code, it's only rendering

my view :

```
<div class="pagination">
   <ul><li><%= will_paginate @organizations %></li></ul>
 </div>
```

My source code:

```
<ul><li><div class="pagination">
<span class="previous_page disabled">&#8592; Previous</span>
<em>1</em> 
<a rel="next" href="/organizations?page=2&amp;search=2&amp;submit_search=ok">2</a> 
<a href="/organizations?page=3&amp;search=2&amp;submit_search=ok">3</a> 
<a class="next_page" rel="next" href="/organizations?page=2&amp;search=2&amp;submit_search=ok">Next &#8594;</a>
</div></ul>/<li>
```

I would like to have this kind of result :

```
<div class="pagination"> 
  <ul> 
    <li class="prev"><a href="#"><span>Prev</span></a></li> 
    <li><a href="#"><span>1</span></a></li> 
    <li><a href="#"><span>2</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>3</span></a></li> 
    <li class="next"><a href="#"><span>Next</span></a></li> 
   </ul> 
</div>
```

How can it be done?

Comment: To me at least it's not clear what you're asking. Do you want to wrap the pagination elements in li's?

Comment: I would like to have this kind of result :

<div class="pagination">
<ul>
<li class="prev"><a href="#"><span>Prev</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>1</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>2</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>3</span></a></li>
<li class="next"><a href="#"><span>Next</span></a></li>    
</ul>
</div>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The will_paginate docs [link to an example](http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2008/8/3/roll-your-own-pagination-links-with-will_paginate) that is nearly identical to what you're asking for here.

Scroll down to "Doing it Your Way."